# Reversing The Last 5 Nodes In A Linked List

Tags: c, data-structures

I want to reverse the last 5 nodes in a linked list as follows:

```
Input: 2->4->6->8->10->12->14->16->NULL
Output: 2->4->6->16->14->12->10->8->NULL
```

I have written the following code to perform the above task but my reverse() function is not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

int n;

void insert(struct node **headref, int data) {
    struct node *new_node;
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = *headref;
    *headref = new_node;
}

struct node* create() {
    struct node dummy;
    struct node *new_node = &dummy;
    dummy.next = NULL;
    int i,num;
    printf("Enter The Number Of Data: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        printf("Enter Data %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &num);
        insert(&(new_node->next), num);
        new_node = new_node->next;
    }
    return dummy.next;
}

void display(struct node *head) {
    struct node *current;
    for(current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next) {
        printf("%d  ", current->data);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void reverse(struct node *head) {
    struct node *current, *next, *prev, *temp;
    current = head;
    next = current->next;
    prev = NULL;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n-5; i++) {
        temp = current;
        current = next;
        next = next->next;
    }

    while(current != NULL) {
        current->next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
        next = next->next;
    }

    temp->next = prev;
}

int main() {
    struct node *start = create();
    display(start);
    reverse(start);
    display(start);
}
```

Is there any error in my logic in the reverse() function? I tried the dry run on paper and it should have worked but it isn't working. Please point out the mistake that I made or even better suggest some alternative code to solve this problem.

Comment: When running your program, I get a segfault. What happens when you run the program?

Comment: You should get `reverse` working, this is the only real challenge.  Then just call `reverse` on your input list offset by 5 nodes from the head.

Comment: Please be more specific in describing the behaviour of your program than "not working". What exactly do you observe? Does it crash? Does it delete some of the elements? Does it not change the list at all? ...?

Comment: @Timothy I tried to compile and run the code on Dev C++ and after inserting the data and displaying the linked list it giver the error "reverse.exe has stopped working". That is probably occurring while executing the reverse() function

Comment: @kaylum the program crashes after inserting and displaying the linked list. That's probably because of the reverse() function.

Comment: What's `n`? It seems like the number of nodes. That looks bad (the global part, especially).

Comment: @Mihai Why is n being global that bad??

Comment: @BBasak Try to work with two lists at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the line:

```
next = next->next;
```

in this part of the code:

```
while(current != NULL) {
        current->next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
        next = next->next;
    }
```

In the last element, when current becomes the last node current->next is NULL and you try to get next->next->next which gives segmentation fault.
You need to change the above line simply by adding an if statement:

```
 while(current != NULL) {
        current->next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next;
        if (next!=NULL) next = next->next;
    }
```

I tried with your given input and it works!!

Comment: @ David C. Rankin, I tried that but fir example instead of printing 2 4 6 16 14 12 10 8(for input 2 4 6  8 10 12 14 16) it is printing 2 4 6 14 12 10 8 ,so it is missing an element ,also temp is initialized in the function reverse.

Comment: You don't compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` do you?

Comment: @coder Thanks. This program now works perfectly for me too!

Comment: Oh, It is the *compiler warnings* that will flag all instances of uninitialized variables, etc.. Try `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o file file.c`. And, yes, `temp` does get initialized, but conditionally `:)`

Comment: @B.Basak ,glad that helped!!

Comment: I stand corrected, you are right about `next != NULL` chopping the `16` off. I must be getting tired `:)`